# How to delete observation where in some column values do not have certain number of numbers in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame with column: "col1" which has evidence number of clients. This evidence number must have 11 numbers like for example: 56745334512.

My question: How can I delete rows from my DataFrame where in "col1" values do not have 11 elements?

Comment: @not_speshal `df=df[df['col'].astype(str).str.len().eq(11)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your DataFrame is called `df`, try:

```
df = df[df["Col1"].apply(lambda x: len(str(x))) == 11]
```